I connect my coinstats wallet to coinbase but can't find my money
I'm Christopher Lintnaar I from South Africa I connect my coinstats wallet to my coinbase wallet but i can't find it they said is in blockchain smart contract please help me to get my coins or money out of blockchain or coinstats help me please I was scam for 2 year's and I loose my job because of depression about all the scam
WITH MUST THANKS
CHRISTOPHER LINTNAAR


they said is in blockchain smart contract

I believe they are almost certainly lying to you.
From what you write, there is no obvious reason to use smart contracts
The use of a smart contract is never a surprise to participants in any honest transaction.

please help me to get my coins or money out of blockchain or coinstats

From what you write, it seems likely that someone you have been communicating with stole your money and there is nothing in your wallets. That would mean no way to get coins or money out.

I was scam for 2 year's

That makes you a target for other scammers and fake recovery agents who believe you are more likely to be easy for them to deceive. You need to be very careful.
If I was you I would only get advice from public question and answer websites where you can see a history of people correcting bad answers to other questions. I would not ever seek or use advice from people using private messaging if those were people I had only met online.
